# How to test pull request code from GitHub in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: github, intellij-idea, pull-request

I would like to test all acumulated changes on a pull request for a personal project. I mean, i'm the original project creator, and other persons had made a pull request.

I'm seeing the PR list from  IntelliJ: i can view the diff panel to review the code on each PR. But i would like to run the whole code of the PR to test it, before accept, reject, or comment it.

¿How would be the optimal process to make this?

Answer (score 1):

You should checkout the PR to a local branch and run/test the code locally.
To do that you can click the Checkout link after the branch name.

[image]

Or simply checkout the corresponding remote branch.